# jquery validation does not work in php

Tags: php, jquery-validate

Ok it does work in PHP but if I modify the file so that my index.php looks like this

```
<?php

include('header');
include('main_content');
include('footer');

?>
```

then it does not work.

Here is my rendered hmtl (firefox)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=MacRoman">
<title>This is a test page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="js/main.js" ></script>
<LINK href="css/other1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<LINK href="css/other2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<LINK href="css/gallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<LINK href="css/min_jquery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<LINK href="css/minified.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
    <body>

<!-- This is the form ---------->

<form id="form1" method="post" action="jquery_form.php">
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Name *</span><input type="text" name="name" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">E-Mail *</span><input type="text" name="email" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">URL</span><input type="text" name="url" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Your comment *</span><textarea name="comment" ></textarea></div>
      <div class="form-row"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
    </form>

<!-- this is the jQuery validation ----------->

</div></div></body>

</html><script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
          name: "required",// simple rule, converted to {required:true}
          email: {// compound rule
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        url: {
          url: true
        },
        comment: {
          required: true
        }
        },
        messages: {
          comment: "Please enter a comment."
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    element.css('background', '#ffdddd');
                }
      });
    $("#form2").validate({
    rules:{
        name2:"required",
        pass: "required"
    }
})
    });
  </script>
```

What could be wrong? I know the query validation does not work if it is not the first include. But it is the first include in the headers. And rendered HTML looks fine. The file are in the js folder.

I have spend a couple of hours on this.

### This code works

This is rendered code of another html page that does works. jQuery won't submit the form if validation fails.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Simple Form Validation</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    * { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; }
    .submit { margin-left: 125px; margin-top: 10px;}
    .label { display: block; float: left; width: 120px; text-align: right; margin-right: 5px; }
    .form-row { padding: 5px 0; clear: both; width: 700px; }
    label.error { width: 250px; display: block; float: left; color: red; padding-left: 10px; }
    input[type=text], textarea { width: 250px; float: left; }
    textarea { height: 50px; }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" method="post" action="jquery.php">
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Name *</span><input type="text" name="name" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">E-Mail *</span><input type="text" name="email" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">URL</span><input type="text" name="url" /></div>
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Your comment *</span><textarea name="comment" ></textarea></div>
      <div class="form-row"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
    </form>
<p>
<hr>

  </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
          name: "required",// simple rule, converted to {required:true}
          email: {// compound rule
          required: true,
          email: true
        },
        url: {
          url: true
        },
        comment: {
          required: true
        }
        },
        messages: {
          comment: "Please enter a comment."
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    element.css('background', '#ffdddd');
                }
      });
    $("#form2").validate({
    rules:{
        name2:"required",
        pass: "required"
    }
})
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: What's the question? You are outputting some HTML from PHP includes - it looks like that is working fine. If so, this is just a jQuery question. What do you expect to happen and what is happening?

Comment: Yeah, you have to be a bit more descriptive. I have no clue what you are asking.

Comment: what I am asking here is jQuery validation does not work. If you submit the form, the form is submitted without passing through jQuery form validation. Sorry if it was not clear. I have played more with it, created a file of just the above rendered page as html, move the title down, etc but still does not work. Now everything is in one html file.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a valid error message.

Comment: jQuery validation does not work. The form is submitted regardless of the jQuery code. I will update the code as well what works (for comparison)

Comment: I am going to delete this question, since this is such a bad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have included jquery twice, remove the last one.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script> 
<!--  <script src="js/jquery.min.js" ></script>  --/>
```

Also, you may want to use the "id" property on your form fields in addition to name. Name is passed to the server, while id is normally used with javascript.

And move your last script inside the body tag or head tag.

Comment: As far as I know in jQuery Validatino, `form_id` is required and `form_field_names` are required. Remove the other instance did not work. I will update the code above too.

Comment: Kill the </div></div> that does not belong anywhere. (after the form). try the stuff in firefox with firebug or ie/chrome with debug panel (F12) and see what the script debugger tells you.

Comment: This was part of the problem but not the whole problem. The other js file I included `min.'s` had some errors (found out after debugging), excluding that file made everything work. Although I still need to fix that JS as it has my own script.

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess, but try moving the `<script>` block before the closing `</body>` tag. It's not clear which include'd file contains what, but nothing should come after your closing `</body>` tag.